# how to "join" two vertices on Gremlin?

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin

I meet some trouble with Gremlin console; here is my schema.

[image: gremlin]

Knowing:

- ID 1 (vertex)
- ID 3 (vertex)
- Label: "created" (edge)

I would like to get ID 9 (edge)

> v = g.v(1)
>
> v.outE("created").id

only works if there is only one "created" edge

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
g.e(9)
```

or, filtering from v[1]:

```
g.v(1).outE('created')[[id:9]]
```

or, if you mean getting the created edges between vertex 1 and 3:

```
g.v(1).outE('created').as('x').inV[[id:3]].back('x').id
g.v(1).outE('created').inV[[id:3]].back(2).id
```

Hope that helps,
Marko.

http://markorodriguez.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Marko, it works fine (but I have to use id:'3' instead of id:3).

And by the way, is this code:

```
g.v(1).outE('created').as('x').inV[[id:'3']].back('x').id
```

more efficient than this one:

```
g.v(1).outE.as('x').inV[[id:'3']].back('x').id
```